# Tools for weak relationships

Tags: predictive-models

What are the possible data analysis tools that may be sensitive to weak relationships?

I intent to explore relationship (if any) between weather and employee absenteeism. However the "traditional" models such as lm and tree are fairly inconsequential. I don't intend to overfit my model but still would like to try more tools.

Many thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically speaking, if you apply any method with high level of significance, say 10%, it will become more sensitive to smaller effects. This is the way how exploratory statistics is used in marketing or social sciences, where type I. error is not so much disastrous thing to happen.

Applying a regression tree in your case should be the one to start with, as it has few assumptions. However, some tree methods fail in case where the prior distribution is too unbalanced (such as bin sizes with classification trees).